# Debugging vulnerable binary using GDB

Tags: c, integer, gdb, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to exploit this vulnerable code from [Phrack Magazine](http://phrack.org/issues/60/10.html). This is the code of the vulnerable binary:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        unsigned short s;
        int i;
        char buf[80];

        if(argc < 3){
                return -1;
        }

        i = atoi(argv[1]);
        s = i;

        if(s >= 80){            /* [w1] */
                printf("Oh no you don't!\n");
                return -1;
        }

        printf("s = %d\n", s);

        memcpy(buf, argv[2], i);
        buf[i] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buf);

        return 0;
}
```

I succeeded to got the integer that can bypass the verification which is 65536 when it casted to unsigned short it will be equal to 0, but when I tried to put some "A" to find the position of the return address (EIP), I got this error:
This is my payload:

> (gdb) r 65536 $(python -c 'print "A"*65536')

when I look into the problem it was here:

```
  `0x08048532 <+182>:   lea    0x1a(%esp),%edx
   0x08048536 <+186>:   mov    0x5c(%esp),%eax
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x0804853a <+190>:   add    %edx,%eax
=> 0x0804853c <+192>:   movb   $0x0,(%eax)
   0x0804853f <+195>:   lea    0x1a(%esp),%eax
   0x08048543 <+199>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048546 <+202>:   call   0x8048350 <puts@plt>
   0x0804854b <+207>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x08048550 <+212>:   leave
   0x08048551 <+213>:   ret`
```

But I don't understanding why this is happening to me.

Comment: _I got this error:_ What error? What problem?